# SELECT in PHP - looking for ID MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm writing a script, which shows records from database in a table.
Last time i wanted to improve my script by adding "delete" option next to each table's tr. 
When i want to delete a record i use delete query and everything is fine. The problem is that when i want to add a record, it's getting duplicate(probably, because that i use counting rows in database and then getting id from this). I started to think - "How to make a proper way to keep adding next records without interfereing  other ID's" and then i got an idea to get a MAX value from the table and than increament it and here is the problem. 
I have an operation like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Id FROM `table` where Id = (SELECT max(Id) FROM table)"
```

In PHPmyAdmin it works, it returns me MAX Id, but i can't assign returned value to variable and then increment it(STRING error or smth can't really remember).
What to do next? when i want to get only one value, make a variable with this value and increment it to get next ID in database? Any other and better ideas how to make optimal adding and deleting records through the page?

UPDATE: 
I'm trying to make an autoincrement column but when i make smth like this:

> $sql="CREATE TABLE table(Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Nick
>   CHAR(30), Xpos INT, Ypos INT, Punkty INT, Ratuszlvl INT, Koszarylvl
>   INT, Stajnialvl INT, Warsztatlvl INT, Kuznialvl INT, Ryneklvl INT,
>   Tartaklvl INT, Cegielnialvl INT, Hutalvl INT, Zagrodalvl INT,
>   Spichlerzlvl INT, Schoweklvl INT, Murlvl INT, Palaclvl INT, Data DATE,
>   Czas TIME)";

I got the result

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it
>   must be defined as a key

Comment: Isn't your query redundant? Just use `SELECT max(Id) FROM table`.

Comment: Can't you just use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: Niet is right, you should use `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: always have `AUTO_INCREMENT` that makes `CRUD` job easier...

Comment: You should be able to assign this result to a variable and increment it. If you're having trouble with that, please post THAT code, so we can help you understand what you're doing wrong. Saying that you got an error that you don't remember is not helpful.

Comment: @user3576397 After your edit: Your query won't return any rows. There can't be a row with an Id that is greater than the maximum of all Ids in your table. Why can't you use simply an AUTO_INCREMENT column as Niet the Dark Absol said first. Your current approach will lead to other problems too.

Comment: Maybe you should run the Coop bank. Seriously, this is a disaster in the making.

Comment: @user3576397 The definition of your first column is missing PRIMARY KEY, see [first example, manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html): `Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,` ... but I fear the same as Strawberry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the id be autoincremental ni the database-schema `(would be {value for column a})`. (thats why it's not  assigned in the insert-statement.)

Just do like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES({value for column b}, {value for column c})
```

Here's an example:

**DB-Schema**:

```
Name of table: 
    groovy_machines

Columns:
    id (autoincrement, primary key)
    name (varchar, name of groovymachine)
    color (int, color of groovy machine)
```

**Insertion**

```
INSERT INTO 'groovy_machines' (
    'wonderhelicopter',5, 
    'grasshopperbike', 10,
    'dontgemewrongstoppermachine', 12
);
```

**UPDATE:**
When creating an autoincremental column you must also assign it as a primary key, just as the mysql error states for you.

```
CREATE TABLE `groovy_machines` (
    `id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
)
```

Your creation of table could look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `Nick` CHAR(30), 
    `Xpos` INT, 
    `Ypos` INT, 
    `Punkty` INT, 
    `Ratuszlvl` INT, 
    `Koszarylvl` INT, 
    `Stajnialvl` INT, 
    `Warsztatlvl` INT, 
    `Kuznialvl` INT, 
    `Ryneklvl` INT, 
    `Tartaklvl` INT, 
    `Cegielnialvl` INT, 
    `Hutalvl` INT, 
    `Zagrodalvl` INT, 
    `Spichlerzlvl` INT, 
    `Schoweklvl` INT, 
    `Murlvl` INT, 
    `Palaclvl` INT,
    `Data` DATE, 
    `Czas` TIME,    
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
)
```

Comment: So 'wonderhelicopter' here is a name and 5 is a color, I don't have to take care of ID if i'll make an autoincremental column?

Comment: I have something like this
    $sql="CREATE TABLE table(Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Nick CHAR(30), Xpos INT, Ypos INT, Punkty INT, Ratuszlvl INT, Koszarylvl INT, Stajnialvl INT, Warsztatlvl INT, Kuznialvl INT, Ryneklvl INT, Tartaklvl INT, Cegielnialvl INT, Hutalvl INT, Zagrodalvl INT, Spichlerzlvl INT, Schoweklvl INT, Murlvl INT, Palaclvl INT, Data DATE, Czas TIME)";

And this is a result: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: @user3576397 - you don't have to take care/worry about the actual id when inserting new values no, but of course you must know which id it is when you for example want to do an update. As the MySQL gives you: "...it must be defined as a key" ... Usually the id with autocolumn is  a primary key, so check my update for an example.

Comment: everything works perfectly. Good explanations, working examples, clear code. All of the cases should be solved like this. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, i'd like to ask something more...
Is there any way of optimizing this? 
I mean i have Id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and i deleted 3 and 5, can i move higher ID's to make them 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: @user3576397 - please make a new question of that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use **max(Id)+1** so it will gives you directly incremental value and store into variable directly.

Put:

```
SELECT max(Id)+1 FROM table
```

Comment: That can lead to a race condition.

Comment: $variable = mysqli_query($con, $sql); When i use it i have an error. How to read only one thing from db?

Comment: if your query was successful then `$variable` will be a mysqli_result object, not a value. You've got to use i.e. `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($variable);` and then use `$row[0]` to get to your desired value.

Comment: You COULD do like this, BUT max(id+1) COULD be already be assigned and therefore this is not a good solution.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it can't be already assigned because, next record i add is MAX + 1, so it can't exist.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: That's very true. That is the race condition I mentioned. Between getting this value and using it another process could have used this same value first.